# in zend zfdata grid remove pdf, excel and other export option

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

In the code below, if I comment out the line `$grid->setExport(array('pdf', 'csv','excel','wordx'));`, I get all the default values like pdf, excel and other formats.

How do I remove `setExport` from the code below?

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('./application/configs/grid.ini', 'production');
$grid = Bvb_Grid::factory('Table', $config, $id);
$grid->setEscapeOutput(false);
$grid->setExport(array('pdf', 'csv','excel','wordx'));
return $grid;
```

Comment: Have you tried $grid->setExport(array())?

Comment: well thank you.. I was trying to pass null value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$grid->setExport(array());
```

Is what you're looking for.